# Need to find a surjective function from N to Z, which is not injective.

Tags: functions

Is it possible to find a function like this? I know how to find a bijective function from N to Z, but I have no idea with a just surjective one.

Comment: Map $1$ to $0$, $2$ to $-1$, $3$ to $-1$, $4$ to $1$, $5$ to $1$, $ 6$ to $-2$, $\cdots$.

Comment: One such mapping can be $f(n)=\lfloor n/4\rfloor$ if $n\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$ and $f(n)=-\lfloor n/4\rfloor$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we define an surjective but not injective function $g:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ by putting $g(x)=x$ for each $x\le 0$ and $g(x)=x-1$ for each $x>0$. Now
let $f$ be any bijective function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$. Then a composition $g\circ f$ is a surjective function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$, which is not injective.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness I preassume that $0\in\mathbb N$ but this is not an essential preassumption.

Let $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$ be a bijective function (constructed by yourself).

Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$ be prescribed by $2n\mapsto g(n)$ and $2n+1\mapsto g(n)$.